# How do I code Google query variables referring to text with an apostrophe in it?

Tags: variables, google-sheets, google-query-language

Although I can find solutions to errors caused when a simple text value in a Google query contains an apostrophe, I cannot yet find a solution to when a variable in a Google query might (or might not) refer to a text value that contains an apostrophe.

I am using a simple code to extract a value (column B) related to a list of schools (column A), some of which have apostrophes in their names.

```
  query(SchoolsData_db,"select B where A = '"&$A13&"' label B ''")
```

For all of the schools with apostrophes I get a #VALUE! error.

I am wondering if there is code I can run against the variable itself ('"&$A13&"') to handle the possible apostrophe. I know I can create a "cleaned name" column corollary to the school names, and then a reverse lookup to restore the names with my results table, but I am hoping the problem can be solved in each calculation instead.

Comment: FYI - Apostrophe-CMS (one of your tags) is a content management system written in JavaScript for Node.js. You probably don't want it in your tags for this question - it doesn't seem related at all.

Also, in the future, you should try to give more context about your problem. For example, it would have been helpful to know where this data is coming from (if a database, then is it sql server, mysql, oracle, mongodb, etc), and what language your code is in.

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the tag @Joseph mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You might try creating a variable first and concatenating that to the query string.

Comment: Could you please give an example (or better yet, relate it to my code) to demonstrate your thinking. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

OK - interpreting the suggestion I got, I created and included a text ID column in the schools data (ex: S0001, etc.) and then I used that ID as my variable in the query. All is well. Thanks. I hope others can find this if they are similarly perplexed.

Comment: P.S. This bypasses the actual variable text value with an apostrophe problem. I would love to see a solution that confronts this challenge directly.